# Unit variance normalization of signal (EMG)

Tags: matlab, signals, signal-processing, normalization

I have a matrix of EMG signals m*n, n is the number of muscles and m is just the activation value at that time point, I'm trying to do a unit-variance normalization on this matrix. Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

The unit variance makes sense when you have a vector.
Since you mention that each row represents a time sample I assume you want to have each row (sample vector) with variance 1. To make the things simpler let's also transform the rows to have mean zero.

Starting with an arbitrary real matrix `A`.

```matlab
A = A - mean(A, 2); % subtract the average of each row
A = A / sqrt(mean(A.^2, 2)); % divide each row by the standard deviation
```

Note that If any row has variance zero, the whole row will be assigned to `nan`.